# Est-ce que on peut utiliser les pronoms d'objets direct ou indirects pour exprimer un preposition?

Tags: grammaire, prépositions, compléments

Je me demande s'il est possible d’utiliser les mots "**le**" ou "**en**" pour dire "**from there**" ou "**on it**".

Par exemple, si je veux traduire la phrase "Paul jumped on the table.", au lieu de dire "Paul a sauté au-dessus de la table." puis-je dire "Paul l'a sauté." ou une autre phrase avec un pronom équivalent.

En bref, ces pronoms qu'on utilise pour remplacer les phrases "to someone (something)" ou "of it", puis-je les utiliser pour d'autres prépositions comme "from", "on", ou "off". Si oui, est-ce que ça se fait couramment dans la langue parlée ou écrite ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"Paul jumped on the table" se traduit par "Paul a sauté sur la table".
"Paul jumped over the table" se traduit par "Paul a sauté au-dessus de la table".

Le groupe nominal (sur la table ou au-dessus de la table) est un complément d'objet indirect qui ne peut être remplacé par un pronom personnel (le, la l') complément d'objet direct du verbe sauter.
Si on prend la phrase "Paul a sauté l'obstacle", on peut alors dire "Paul l'a sauté".

Le pronom complément indirect remplace un nom de personnes précédé d'une  préposition, "à" en général. Il répond à la question à qui ? à quoi ? d'où ? de quoi ? Les pronoms indirects sont essentiellement : *me, te, lui, nous, vous, leur, en*.

```
"He comes from London"    -> "il en vient".  
"he got off the train"    -> "il en est sorti".  
"He works on the project" -> "il y travaille".  
"He wrote to her brother" -> "il lui a écrit".
```

Comment: Ou bien _par dessus la table_ pour "over the table".

Comment: Merci pour la réponse. Juste un autre petit doute : est-ce que je suis permis d'utiliser les pronoms complément indirect afin de traduire "from somebody” ? Par exemple, si je veux dire "The question sprung into her head." ou "The question sprang from her mind." puis-je la traduire en "La question lui a jailli.” ?

Comment: @YohannesTimket  La question lui est venue à l'esprit. La question a surgi (jailli) de esprit.

Comment: [...] de **son** esprit.

Comment: @None Je voulais plutôt dire est-ce que on peut aberger la phrase "Elle tient ce caractère de son père", est-ce que on peut écrire "Elle en tient.", "Elle le tient.", ou quelque chose avec un pronom comme ceux-là.

Comment: @jlliagre oui, bien sûr... j'avais oublié un mot !

Comment: @YohannesTimket Ce sale caractère elle **le** tient de son père.

Comment: @None Oui, mais si on veut substituer "de son père" à un pronom, peut-on dire "Elle en le tient." ou utiliser un autre pronom ?

Comment: @YohannesTimket  "Son père a une forte personnalité et son sale caractère elle le tient de **lui**".  On ne peut pas utiliser **en** dans ta phrase.

Comment: @YohannesTimket Que veux-tu dire par *aberger* ?

Comment: Il veut dire **remplacer** je suppose. Et comme mettre un pronom ça fait plus court (en général) il  abrège. Je suis sûr que t'avais compris !

Comment: @None Ah, *abréger*, non, je n'avais pas compris le mot.

Comment: @None Je vois bien ce que vous dites. Alors de quoi s'agit-il quand je croise les phrases comme "Je ne sais pas ce que vous me voulez." dans les divertissements; ce n'est pas "I do not know what you want **from me**."?

Comment: @YohannesTimket Ta phrase *Je ne sais pas ce que vous me voulez* est parfaitement correct.  Que veux-tu de moi ? What do you want from me?

Comment: @YohannesTimket *Je ne sais pas ce que vous me voulez* est parfaitement correct. *Je ne sais pas ce que vous voulez de moi* est aussi parfaitement correct. Après la préposition *de* on emploi *moi* (pronom personnel tonique)

Comment: @None Alors, c'est correct de remplacer les mots comme **de moi**, **de lui**, **de toi** et **de nous** avec leurs pronoms indirects équivalents ? Comme **"Elle le lui tient"**? Ou est-ce que juste pour des verbes certains ?

Comment: @YohannesTimket On pourrait avoir une phrase comme *elle le lui tient* mais peut-être pas dans n'importe quel contexte. Que représente *le* et *lui* ? Peut-être que dans certains contextes il faudrait dire *elle tient ça de lui*.  J'ai l'impression qu'on est loin de la question que tu as posé au départ. Si tu rencontres une autre difficulté il vaut mieux poser une autre question.

Comment: @YohannesTimket *Elle le lui tient* signifie généralement *Elle le tient **pour** lui* (elle tient quelque chose pour lui).

Comment: @YohannesTimket par rapport au premier commentaire : "je suis permis de..." n’est pas correct. En français, le sujet d’une forme passive doit correspondre à un complément d’objet direct (et non indirect) dans la forme active. Pour traduire "I am allowed to do X" de façon littérale, on utilisera soit "il m’est permis de faire X" (tournure impersonnelle), soit "Faire X m’est permis". D’autres options seraient "je suis autorisé à faire X", "j’ai le droit de faire X"...

Comment: @YohannesTimket ...dans le cas d’espèce, le plus idiomatique est sans doute "je peux (utiliser telle ou telle formulation)". Les constructions avec _permettre_, _autoriser_, _avoir le droit_ impliquent l’existence d’une autorité clairement identifiée qui édicte les règles - "il n’est pas permis de fumer dans la gare" parce que la loi ou le règlement l’interdit - ce qui n’est pas le cas de "pouvoir".